# Adding a program with variable PIDs to cgroup

Tags: cgroups

Specifically, I am seeking a solution that can add the program to the cgroup in a seamless and consistent manner.

**What is the recommended approach to dynamically adding a program to cgroup, such as Firefox, without having to manually track its PID every time it spawns new PIDs?**